# How to check java Character List there is any value besides C or N

Tags: java, list, char

I have `List<Character>` and i'm trying need to figure out how to check weather there is any value besides C or N in the list

```
String sql = "SELECT distinct(CODE_STATUS_TYPE) FROM AMEQPS_REWQUEST.PSFDSS_CR_TB " +
             " WHERE  NBR_CR_KEY != :nbrCrKey";


Query q = em.createNativeQuery(sql).setParameter("nbrCrKey", cdId);
List<Character> codeStatus = (ArrayList<Character>) q.getResultList();

// THIS WILL RETURN ANYTHING W,R,D,C,N
```

Would `if` block like this be efficient? Thank you Is this proper data check?

```
if(!codeStatus.contains('C')&&!codeStatus.contains('N')){

}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the above approach you are iterate the `List` twice and checking it has `C` or `N`, but by using [stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) and [allMatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#allMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-) you can complete in one iteration

```
codeStatus.stream().allMatch(c->c.equals('N') || c.equals('C'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `Stream`, you can do it as follows:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Character> codeStatus = Arrays.asList(new Character[] { 'C','N'});
        System.out.println(!codeStatus.stream().allMatch(c->c.equals('N') || c.equals('C')));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
false
```

**Another run:**
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.List;

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Character> codeStatus = Arrays.asList(new Character[] { 'C','N','T'});
        System.out.println(!codeStatus.stream().allMatch(c->c.equals('N') || c.equals('C')));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
true
```

If you do not want to use `Stream`, you can do it as follows:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Character> codeStatus = Arrays.asList(new Character[] { 'C','N','T'});
        if (codeStatus.size()==0){
            System.out.println("The list does not contain any element");
        } else if (codeStatus.size()==1) {
            if(codeStatus.contains('C') || codeStatus.contains('N')) {
                System.out.println("Either 'C' or 'N' exists");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Neither 'N' nor 'C' exists");
            }            
        } else if(codeStatus.size()==2) {
            if (codeStatus.contains('C') && codeStatus.contains('N')) {
                System.out.println("Only 'C' and 'N' exists");
            } else if((codeStatus.contains('C') || codeStatus.contains('N'))){
                System.out.println("Other than 'C' or 'N', some other character(s) exist(s)");
            }
        }else if (codeStatus.size()>2) {
            if((codeStatus.contains('C') && codeStatus.contains('N'))) {
                System.out.println("Other than 'C' and 'N', some other character(s) exist(s)");
            }else if((codeStatus.contains('C') || codeStatus.contains('N'))){
                System.out.println("Other than 'C' or 'N', some other character(s) exist(s)");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Neither 'N' nor 'C' exists");
            }           
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Other than 'C' and 'N', some other character(s) exist(s)
```